# babel-core: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-core

This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'/>
  <title>Sandbox</title>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js'></script>
  <script src='js/index.js' type='text/babel'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='foo'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my `js/index.js` file:

```
"use strict";

window.onload = function(){
  const stuff = () => document.getElementById('foo').textContent = 'Hello!'
  stuff()
}
```

I get the error in Google Chrome v64.0.3282.140 when I open my HTML-file:

[image]

Why does it happen?

Comment: You should use `babel-standalone` instead `babel-core`. That issue is widely reported in many places.

Comment: Thank you, @Dez!